# How to pass in the 'this' pointer to a C++ WinAPI thread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am trying to run a C++ thread but also pass in the instance to the class itself. I cannot seem to figure it out.

I have a struct for parameters to the thread:

```
struct CLASS_PARAMS {
    SomeClass* ptr;
};
```

I then call my setup method:

```
void SomeClass::setup() {
    CLASS_PARAMS params;
    params.ptr = this;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, SetupThread, &params, 0, NULL);
}
```

and right above `SomeClass::setup()`, I define `SetupThread`:

```
DWORD WINAPI SetupThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
    CLASS_PARAMS* params = (CLASS_PARAMS *) lpParam;
    SomeClass* inst = params->ptr;
    ....
    ....
}
```

However, I get read-access violations on using `inst`. I have other methods in `SomeClass` that I need to access via the thread:

```
inst->getSomeValue();
...
inst->setSomeValue(someValue);
...
```

but it will not allow me. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Race condition: the `params` variable has ceased to exist by the time the thread started executing.

Comment: You don't need all that C-level hackery. `std::thread` is designed for C++; use it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate `CLASS_PARAMS` on stack, so it is destroyed before used.

Allocate it dynamically, pass pointer and free it in the thread.

Alternatively, if you need to pass only `this`, pass it without wrapping structure, just cast to `LPVOID` and back (but be sure to use the same class pointer type to avoid pointer adjustment bugs)

Comment: Thank you sir. Casting `this` to a `LPVOID` and back worked perfectly.